# mySQL full text search for two letter words

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb

I have data on a mySQL server running on InnoDB engine. I have enabled full text search on the columns (street, city, state, zip) with the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE address_table ADD FULLTEXT(street, city, state, zip) 

+---------------+---------+-------+-----+
|    street     |  city   | state | zip |
+---------------+---------+-------+-----+
|32 Congress St | Boston  |  MA   | 060 |
|31 Congress St | Nashua  |  NH   | 050 |
+---------------+---------+-------+-----+
```

All of the columns are of varchar datatype. I need to search by the state so I've set `innodb_ft_min_token_size = 2` and restarted the server. I also verified the server variable update.

However, the query 
`select * from address_table WHERE MATCH (street, city, state, zip) AGAINST ('NH' IN BOOLEAN MODE);` returns 0 results. What could be the problem?

My main problem is that the query `select * from address_table WHERE MATCH (street, city, state, zip) AGAINST ('31 Congress St, Nashua, NH' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` also returns 0 results;

Comment: What is wrong with just doing a normal `select * from address_table where state like ‘NH’`? What problem are you trying to solve doing it the other way?

Comment: You also need to recreate the index (an `optimize table address_table` should do it). But in general, as aaron suggested, if you know that you want to search for a specific state, searching in the state-column may be more productive, as the fulltext search might also find 2 letter symbols in street/city which might look like state codes but aren't.

Comment: @AaronMorefield please see edit. The second query is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you @Solarflare. I thought that the statement `ALTER TABLE address_table ADD FULLTEXT(street, city, state, zip) ` would be enough to execute after changing `innodb_ft_min_token_size`  but the statement you've suggested fixed the problem!

Comment: Yes, adding the index would have been enough, but only if done after the restart (so after the new setting took place), which you probably didn't do in that order. Any `alter` to the table would actually be fine, `optimize` is used here basically as an `alter` without changing anything.

Comment: What percentage of the table has `NH`?

Comment: @RickJames since the search is in BOOLEAN mode it doesn't really matter. I had to recreate the index with `optimize` to solve my problem.